# Who will initialize the data members? Is it a constructor or any thing?

Tags: c#

If it is default constructor, who will initialize the member variables to zero then how come this will be possible

```
class A        
{        
    public int i;        
    public int j;        
    public A()        
    {        
       i=12;        
    }        
}        
class Program        
{        
     static void Main(string[] args)        
     {        
         A a = new A();        
         Console.WriteLine(a.i + "" + a.j);        
         Console.ReadLine();          
     }        
}
```

Comment: how come the j will be initialized to zero in the above context

Comment: if the default constructor we declared will be executed by when we declare it as `A a =new A();`

Answer (score 18):

Because field initializers run before constructors. You didn't assign `j` value in your constructor, it will be `0` by default since it is an `int`.

From [10.4.4 Field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value ([Section 5.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) of the field's
>   type.

Who do that? Well, looks like [`newobj`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does that when you call `new`. Take a look [dyatchenkos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627109/447156) for more details.

Comment: I think OP _already_ knows that and asking where this initialization is happening.

Comment: @Selman22 what do you mean "where"? C# is compiled into the MSIL code, and then, after compilation, it will be smth like this `public int j = 0;`

Comment: @dyatchenko I have checked the generated IL code. and there is no code that initializes j to 0.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between the initial zeroing and when field initializers run.

Comment: @CodesInChaos dyatchenkos' answer mentioned this subject and I linked to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

A field initialization happens before a constructor call through the `newobj` command. It is easy to check after decompilation of the executable with the following C# code:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class A { public int j; }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A g = new A();
            Console.WriteLine(g.j);
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the decompilted MSIL code (method main):

```
//000017:         {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000018:             A g = new A();
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.A::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
//000019:             Console.WriteLine(g.j);
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldfld      int32 ConsoleApplication1.A::j
    IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0012:  nop
//000020:         }
```

As we can see the MSIL uses the `newobj` instruction to create an instance of the A class. According to the following [microsoft acticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The newobj instruction allocates a new instance of the class associated 
>   with ctor and initializes **all the fields in the new instance to 0** (of the 
>   proper type) or null references as appropriate. It then calls the 
>   constructor ctor with the given arguments along with the newly created 
>   instance. After the constructor has been called, the now initialized 
>   object reference (type O) is pushed on the stack.

If it is wrong, please comment, otherwise assign it as a right answer, please.

Comment: I think the memory is actually zeroed long before the `newobj` instruction is called.  `newobj` always grabs the next unused piece of the gen0 heap, and it's trivial to guarantee that unused sections of the gen0 heap are always zeroed (the memory is zeroed when it comes from the OS, and can be zeroed again when a garbage collection pass happens and compaction turns used memory back to unused)

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `int` variables will always default to 0 unless otherwise specified. In your constructor:

```
public A ()
{
    i=12;
}
```

When your object is instantiated, your `i` property will be initialized to 12, while your `j` property will be initialized to 0.

In your code:

```
public class Program
{
    A a = new A(); // You instantiated your object, i will be assigned 12
    Console.WriteLine(a.i.ToString() + "" + a.j.ToString()); 
    // Your output will be 12 0 because you didn't initialize j so the default is 0
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid here is an another heart of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the fact that c# numeric fields are 0 by default. While in C++ the int field is some random value by default

Comment: Good point :) I'll update the message later (currently in training)

Answer (score 1):

During the instance creation, its variables are made available too.
And since int is not nullable, it initializes with default(int). Which is 0

Answer (score 1):

C# set default `int` to `0` . More about default values found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

And further more since they are fields this [apply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an instance field, is the default value.

Default constructor will assign `i` to `12` but `j` will have `0` as the `default` value since it haven't been assigned anywhere in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

If in your program, there is no prog-defined constructor then the system will create a default constructor during the time of compilation which is known as **"system defined default constructor".**

system-defined default constructor - will assign the default values to the data members of your class.

You can check this out --> Do not define any constructor in your class and compile your java program.After you compile type the command **javap className** and press Enter.
You will find your class definition in which you will have default constructor and it does not have any statement in body part provided by the compiler.